# How to insert multiple strings into variable

Tags: sql, mysql

I was creating a dynamic query inside a procedure. However, several strings need to be concatenated. At this point I used the `CONCAT()` function. But the result is always returning 0.
MyQuery:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getSearchCounts`(IN fDate varchar(20), IN tDate varchar(20), IN byName varchar(255), IN byInn varchar(255), IN byTrademark varchar(255), IN byDist varchar(255), IN byDf varchar(255), IN byDFG varchar(255), IN byDt varchar(255), IN byDTG varchar(255), IN byCompany varchar(255), IN byMf varchar(255), IN byCountry varchar(255), IN isActive tinyint(1), IN isDeleted tinyint(1))
BEGIN
  DECLARE qWhere varchar(255);
  DECLARE lJoin varchar(255);
  DECLARE gBy varchar(255);
  set qWhere = '';
  SET lJoin = '';
  set gBy = ' dr.drug_id';
  IF (byName != '') THEN
    set qWhere := CONCAT(' AND dr.drug_id IN(', byName, ')');
  END IF;
  IF (byInn != '') THEN
    SET qWhere = CONCAT(@qWhere, ' AND d.di_id IN (', byInn, ')');
    SET gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.di_id');
  END IF;
  IF (byTrademark != '') THEN
    SET qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.trademark_id IN (', byTrademark, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.trademark_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byDist != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND dr.m40d_id IN (', byDist, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', dr.m40d_id');
  END IF;
  IF (byDf != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.df_id IN (', byDf, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.df_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byDFG != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.dfg_id IN (', byDFG, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.dfg_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byDt != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.dt_id IN (', byDt, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.dt_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byDTG != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.dtg_id IN (', byDTG, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.dtg_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byMf != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND dr.mf_id IN (', byMf, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', dr.mf_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byCompany != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND dr.sc_id IN (', byCompany, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', dr.sc_id');
  END IF;
  IF (byCountry != '') THEN
    SET lJoin = ' LEFT JOIN manufacturers as mf ON dr.mf_id = mf.id ';
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND mf.country_id IN (', byDist, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', mf.country_id');
  END IF;

  SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(resData) AS counts FROM (SELECT dr.drug_id AS resData FROM drug_reports dr 
  LEFT JOIN drugs as d ON dr.drug_id = d.id ', lJoin,
  ' WHERE dr.mode_40_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE("', fDate, '", "%m.%d.%Y") AND STR_TO_DATE("', tDate, '", "%m.%d.%Y") AND dr.is_active = ', isActive, ' AND dr.is_deleted = ', isDeleted, qWhere,' GROUP BY ', gBy, ' ) AS dd');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

If I use `SELECT @q;` it returns:

```
"SELECT COUNT(resData) AS counts FROM (SELECT dr.drug_id AS resData FROM drug_reports dr 
  LEFT JOIN drugs as d ON dr.drug_id = d.id  LEFT JOIN manufacturers as mf ON dr.mf_id = mf.id  WHERE dr.mode_40_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(""01.01.2018"", ""%m.%d.%Y"") AND STR_TO_DATE(""01.01.2023"", ""%m.%d.%Y"") AND dr.is_active = 1 AND dr.is_deleted = 0 AND dr.drug_id IN(4468,4469) AND d.di_id IN ('') AND d.trademark_id IN ('') AND dr.m40d_id IN ('') AND d.df_id IN ('') AND d.dfg_id IN ('') AND d.dt_id IN ('') AND d.dtg_id IN ('') AND dr.mf_id IN ('') AND dr.sc_id IN ('') AND mf.country_id IN ('') GROUP BY dr.drug_id, d.di_id, d.trademark_id, dr.m40d_id, d.df_id, d.dfg_id, d.dt_id, d.dtg_id, dr.mf_id, dr.sc_id, mf.country_id ) AS dd"
```

It always returns 0. I also used @var. However, in this case, it only works once. It returns 0 the rest of the time.
How to concatenate multiple strings into a single variable?

Comment: The variable `xgBy` is not declared !

Comment: @SelVazi I fixed it. There was an error while I was typing. But that's not the reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue on line 13 :

Instead of `SET qWhere = CONCAT(@qWhere, ' AND d.di_id IN (', byInn, ')');`
It should be : `SET qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.di_id IN (', byInn, ')');`

Also `qWhere` should be increased to `varchar(1024);`

If you continue to get an empty result, capture the global select (Add `SELECT @q;` before `PREPARE stmt FROM @q;`) and try executing it directly to see what happens.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getSearchCounts`(IN fDate varchar(20), 
  IN tDate varchar(20), IN byName varchar(255), IN byInn varchar(255),
  IN byTrademark varchar(255), IN byDist varchar(255), IN byDf varchar(255),
  IN byDFG varchar(255), IN byDt varchar(255), IN byDTG varchar(255), 
  IN byCompany varchar(255), IN byMf varchar(255), 
  IN byCountry varchar(255), IN isActive tinyint(1), 
  IN isDeleted tinyint(1))
BEGIN
  DECLARE qWhere varchar(1024);
  DECLARE lJoin varchar(255);
  DECLARE gBy varchar(255);
  set qWhere = '';
  SET lJoin = '';
  set gBy = ' dr.drug_id';
  IF (byName != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(' AND dr.drug_id IN(', byName, ')');
  END IF;

  IF (byInn != '') THEN
    SET qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.di_id IN (', byInn, ')');
    SET gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.di_id');
  END IF;
  IF (byTrademark != '') THEN
    SET qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.trademark_id IN (', byTrademark, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.trademark_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byDist != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND dr.m40d_id IN (', byDist, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', dr.m40d_id');
  END IF;
  IF (byDf != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.df_id IN (', byDf, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.df_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byDFG != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.dfg_id IN (', byDFG, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.dfg_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byDt != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.dt_id IN (', byDt, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.dt_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byDTG != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND d.dtg_id IN (', byDTG, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', d.dtg_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byMf != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND dr.mf_id IN (', byMf, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', dr.mf_id');
  END IF;

  IF (byCompany != '') THEN
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND dr.sc_id IN (', byCompany, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', dr.sc_id');
  END IF;
  IF (byCountry != '') THEN
    SET lJoin = ' LEFT JOIN manufacturers as mf ON dr.mf_id = mf.id ';
    set qWhere = CONCAT(qWhere, ' AND mf.country_id IN (', byDist, ')');
    set gBy = CONCAT(gBy, ', mf.country_id');
  END IF;

  SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(resData) AS counts FROM (SELECT dr.drug_id AS resData FROM drug_reports dr 
  LEFT JOIN drugs as d ON dr.drug_id = d.id ', lJoin,
  ' WHERE dr.mode_40_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE("', fDate, '", "%m.%d.%Y") AND STR_TO_DATE("', tDate, '", "%m.%d.%Y") AND dr.is_active = ', isActive, ' AND dr.is_deleted = ', isDeleted, qWhere,' GROUP BY ', gBy, ' ) AS dd');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But that didn't work either. 0 is returning only.

Comment: Catch the query using `SELECT @q;` and see what return

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by checking to null and empty value after looking SELECT @q;